# How to make two text box appear in same jqgrid column

Tags: jqgrid

Can anyone be specific of how to make two text boxes in same jqgrid column.

Scenario : I Have a dynamic table which can store address information and more than one address can be entered . For Zipcode , I want store it as a 5 digit textbox and 4 digit text ox in same column. Is is something possible , if Yes then how ?[image]

I have added a sample pic of how I want it to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzVVK/505/) which displays two textboxes in one column.Refer code and change it as per your requirement. This should help you to proceed further.

```
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>

<script>
var mydata = [{
    name: "Toronto",
    country: "Canada",
    continent: "North America"
}, {
    name: "New York City",
    country: "USA",
    continent: "North America"
}, {
    name: "Silicon Valley",
    country: "USA",
    continent: "North America"
}, {
    name: "Paris",
    country: "France",
    continent: "Europe"
}]

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['Zip/Postal',"Name", "Country", "Continent"],
    colModel: [
        {name:'act',index:'act', width:175,sortable:false},
    {
        name: 'name',
        index: 'name',
        editable: true,
    }, {
        name: 'country',
        index: 'country',
        editable: true,
    }, {
        name: 'continent',
        index: 'continent',
        editable: true,
    }],
    pager: '#pager',
    'cellEdit': true,
    'cellsubmit' : 'clientArray',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
gridComplete: function(){ 
    var ids = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    alert(ids);
    for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++)
    {
        var cl = ids[i]; 
        be = "<input style='height:22px;width:40px;' type='text' value='text1'   />"; 
        se = "<input style='height:22px;width:40px;' type='text' value='text2'  />";  jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+se}); }
          }    
});
</script>
```